# Custom annotation in MapKit

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have an application that displays events on a map. Map annotations should be custom set with two images. The first one is a pin with a specific color and the second one, which goes in front of the pin is the icon of represents the type of event. Can I add two images to a view and display that view in place of the default pin? Or do I have to generate an image for each of the possibilities?

Comment: There are really two questions here. First, yes, you can have a custom annotation type that includes a property so that [`viewForAnnotation`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452045-mapview) knows which type of annotation view to return (i.e. a standard `MKPinAnnotationView` or a `MKAnnotationView` whose `image` is set to whatever you want). Then, second, your `viewForAnnotation` can then examine that custom annotation type and dequeue and/or create the correct annotation view type.

Comment: What's unclear here, though, is what this "custom set with two images" means (i.e. is it a question of showing one of the two images or will a single annotation view consist of multiple images somehow). Perhaps you can clarify.

Comment: Finally, if you wanted people to show you examples of what an implementation might look like, you really should tell us whether you're using Swift 3, Swift 2.3, or Objective-C.

Comment: All of this (creating custom annotation objects, creating custom annotation view objects) is described in [Location and Maps Programming Guide: Annotating Maps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW1).

Comment: @Rob I'll show you two pictures at the same time. No background a pin and in front of the pin an icon. I'm using swift 3

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can only pass 1 image for the annotation in the viewFor MapKit delegate function.  You could composite your 2 images in that function, however, and pass those for the view or, if it's less dynamic, simply build a composite image in advance and pass that image.  Since there would be no way to separate the two images once they're displayed on the map, I don't see why this would be worse that passing 2 images through the function - except that you're stuck doing the composite image.